# Foreign key cascade updates propagates all possible columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I couldn't find any suitable explanation on this so here goes:

I have `tableA` and `tableB`.
`tableA` has the fields `column1, column2, column3`.
`tableB` has the fields `columnA, column1, columnC, columnD, columnE`.

`column1` in `tableA` is a **primary key**. `column1` in `tableB` is a **foreign key** that references `column1` in `tableA`. `column1` in `tableB` has a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` **constraint**.

My question then is.. If I change the values of every field in `tableA`, will `tableB` also obtain those same values in its fields?

Comment: What's the point of having two tables with the same data related by a foreign key?  Store the data once.  If you need it from the table that does not have it, join on the foreign key.  Denormalizing data like this is usually a really bad idea and just leads you to problems like this.

Comment: One use is a log table that keeps a running list of records inserted into another table.

Comment: But a log table, by definition, should never be updated.  It's a log.  So the question and concept stands.  If you're logging events, then you should insert a new row to the log when a change is made.

Comment: How will the log table ever recieve any rows if there is nothing to give it those rows? Enter triggers.

Comment: That is a completely different question than what you asked.  On insert, yes, you would use an insert trigger to insert a log row.  On update, a log row shouldn't be touched because that's changing history, making your historical data technically wrong.  You could insert another row on update to log the change, but changing the original log entry is usually not the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way, it'll update just the foreign key in TableB. The constraints in MySQL only updates the related column.

Comment: So are triggers the only way to update respective columns? In that case foreign keys are useless for moving data. They just maintain integrity?

Comment: Exactly, constraints are just to mantain integrity. If you want to update another columns you can try with triggers; but you should consider duplicate information in you database.

Comment: If I have a foreign key relationship but no constraints will I still be able to delete or update rows in a table that is referenced by another table without breaking the referencing table? Can the referencing table have rows that have a blank value in its foreign key column? Or a value that no longer exists in the referenced table? If there are no constraints.